# Pivot chart usage with slicer

Tags: charts, slicers

I have a Pivot data with slicers along with Pivot Chart. In the slicers which selects KPI's, If more than one slicer is selected I wanted the pivot chart to get the secondary axis for the second KPI.

Comment: Please add some data and details.

Comment: For example I have Indicators like  KPIs 0 Level Jan'17 Feb'17 Mar'17
CSAT - IB 3.00 3.00 3.00
NPS - IB 55 5 55
Sales Units - IB  9,999  9,999  9,999 
Sales Units - IB 1 1,638 1,638 1,638
AHT -  - < 850 974 952 989
Sales per FTE  - Units (IB Sales) 150 150 111
Cost per Sale - IB   £ 6.1   £ 7.5   £ 8.2

Comment: Couldn't add an attachment - Headers KPIs 0 Level; Jan'17; Feb'17;Mar'17
Row Items CSAT - IB; NPS - IB; Sales Units - IB; Sales Units - IB 1;AHT -  - < 850; Sales per FTE  - Units (IB Sales); Cost per Sale - IB